# Error loading site in connected mode: Unknown type GraphQLConnectedDemo

Tags: jss

Following the tutorial everything is looking good. The app deploys with no errors using jss deploy app --includeContent --includeDictionary.

I can see the content in Sitecore so thats all good.

However when I view the site I get the following error:

```
Error Rendering Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JsLayoutRenderer: GraphQL error: Unknown type GraphQLConnectedDemo. GraphQL error: Unknown type AppRoute. GraphQL error: Unknown type AppRoute. Error: GraphQL error: Unknown type GraphQLConnectedDemo. GraphQL error: Unknown type AppRoute. GraphQL error: Unknown type AppRoute. at new t (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\S901\dist\example\server.bundle.js:31:327641) at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\S901\dist\example\server.bundle.js:31:346419 at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\S901\dist\example\server.bundle.js:31:353104 at Array.forEach () at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\S901\dist\example\server.bundle.js:31:353084 at Map.forEach () at e.broadcastQueries (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\S901\dist\example\server.bundle.js:31:352991) at Object.next (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\S901\dist\example\server.bundle.js:31:353850) at m (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\S901\dist\example\server.bundle.js:31:404472) at y (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\S901\dist\example\server.bundle.js:31:404838)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.HostingModels.Http.HttpNodeInstance.InvokeExport[T](NodeInvocationInfo invocationInfo)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.HostingModels.OutOfProcessNodeInstance.InvokeExport[T](String moduleName, String exportNameOrNull, Object[] args)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.DefaultNodeServices.InvokeExportWithPossibleRetry[T](String moduleName, String exportedFunctionName, Object[] args, Boolean allowRetry)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.DefaultNodeServices.InvokeExport[T](String moduleName, String exportedFunctionName, Object[] args)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Node.NodeRenderEngine.Invoke[T](String moduleName, String functionName, Object[] functionArgs)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JssRenderer.PerformRender(TextWriter writer, IRenderEngine renderEngine, String moduleName, String functionName, Object[] functionArgs)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JssRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Check also that the site templates, if any, are published. This issue is caused by the site's GraphQL API not being able to find an expected template in Sitecore - and thus not exposing that type to GraphQL. If you load up `/api/jssappname/ui?sc_apikey={yourapikey}` that may provide insights into what is available and what is not in GraphQL. The `Docs` button will let you browse the schema.

Comment: @KamFigy republishing worked for me.  What was odd was that this was done the day before and nothing had changed.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this same error, for me the issue was that I'd used the wrong url during `jss setup`.

Check `/scjssconfig.json` in your React project and verify that `"deployUrl"` and `"layoutServiceHost"` match what is configured in sitecore in `App_Config\Include\zzz\<your project name>.config` under `<site hostname="">`.

Answer (score 0):

Recycling the IIS app pool once will resolve this issue. This is a bug that we fixed in the generally available release.

Comment: This didn't work for Dave

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if your GraphQL endpoint configured in Sitecore does not have the right path on the `templates` configured. It can therefore not find the item template for the `GraphQLConnectedDemo` template.